# Google Test not resetting old tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, googletest

I'm running into this weird problem with Google Test using Visual Studio 2012. I can successfully set up tests and they run just fine. However, when I make change to any code in the test project and build the project, I receive LNK2005 errors, like this one:

```
Error   3   error LNK2005: "private: virtual void __thiscall writeStreamTest_writeRandomDouble_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@writeStreamTest_writeRandomDouble_Test@@EAEXXZ) already defined in UtilsTest.obj    C:\Users\cye\Desktop\codeCPP\unitTest\unitTest.obj  unitTest
```

However, when I change the name of the test, the test runs fine again. But it not only runs the tests after the name change, but also the tests with the old names. Like this:

```
[==========] Running 4 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from writeStreamTest
[ RUN      ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomDouble
[       OK ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomDouble (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomInt
[       OK ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomInt (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomDouble2
[       OK ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomDouble2 (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomInt2
[       OK ] writeStreamTest.writeRandomInt2 (0 ms)
[----------] 4 tests from writeStreamTest (3 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 4 tests from 1 test case ran. (5 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
```

It appears that the tests that were included in the last build would be left over. Therefore when I build the code with the same test name, compiler would complaint that the test with the same name already exists.

If I try to comment out all the tests, then call RUN_ALL_TESTS(), the tests that were included in the last build would still run. If I make change and build again, no test will run.

I'm very confused about this issue. Even after I clean and rebuild the project this issue would still occur.

Anyone else ran into this problem before? Thanks very much!